# Is it safe to use C++ "operator new" rather than CoCreateinstance to create a COM object?

Tags: c++, com

this is probably a noob COM question, but googling this raises more questions than providing answers:

Is it safe to use "operator new" instead of CoCreateInstance for a local COM instance?

What I've done:

1. I implemented the IOperationsProgressDialog interface
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775368(v=vs.85).aspx
   by using public inheritence and thereby also implemented the IUnknown interface.
2. I created an instance via "new RecyclerProgressCallback" and put it into a COM-Ptr for life-time management. "RecyclerProgressCallback" is the name of my derived class.
3. I'm using this instance in IFileOperation::SetProgressDialog
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775803(v=vs.85).aspx

Summary: My approach "seems" to work, but I don't trust it, there's just too much disconcerting information around COM object creation to rely on the observable behavior only.

Are there any subtle risks, fallacies or other problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've even put them on the stack. Andrey's answer (now deleted) incorrectly suggested that it is unsafe, because you bypass COM reference counting. This is faulty reasoning. COM doesn't count references; it delegates the responsibility to you. You have to call `delete`, or `free()`, or whatever your language uses, after COM calls your `Release` method on its last interface. The important word is *after*. Not *when*, because you're not obliged to do so immediately.

Similarly, `CoCreateInstance` is a long detour because COM is language-neutral and doesn't know whether an object must be created with `malloc` or `new`. You do, so just bypass the whole COM logic.

Comment: > just bypass the whole COM logic.
This was what I was hoping to hear! Going the long read, registering new COM objects would not only have been painful in Visual C++ Express, but also would break my application being "portable".

Comment: Well, you still have to correctly implement `IUnknown` since that's part of the `IOperationsProgressDialog` interface you are promising. E.g. your `IOperationsProgressDialog::QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown)` must succeed etc.

Comment: Yeah, I did that. It's good IUnknown is an abstract base class, so I noticed the compiler errors after having implemented IOperationsProgressDialog only. So, the whole procedure, is just ordinary C++ virtual function implemenation... this was simpler than I expected from COM, which makes me suspicious.

Comment: @Zenju, COM taken as a whole is extremely complicated because it's trying to solve *all* the world's problems. At the core though it's really very simple, especially from C++.

Comment: I found a reference implementation from Microsoft in the 7.1 Windows SDK: %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\winui\shell\appplatform\FileOperationProgressSink

It is using "new (std::nothrow) RecyclerProgressCallback" and makes the destructor private, presumably to prevent accidental creation on the stack. So it seems to be official: "new" is allowed for COM object creation.

Comment: Can you give an example where it is safe to create a COM object on the stack? In general it appears dangerous to me, as you often can't make assumptions about the lifetime of pointers to COM objects you are handing out to other API.

Comment: @zett42: One example would be a callback interface for a dialog, as mentioned in the question. Close the dialog, no more callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what exactly you are instantiating. When you are supposed to provide a COM pointer noone asks you whether it is instantiated with COM API, or `new`, or it can sometimes be even object on stack (provided that you manage to ensure it is not destroyed on stack before all references are released).

So the answer is yes, you can use `new` and it would be fine. However, it should be a valid COM interface anyway, it should implement reference counting and `QueryInterface` the way COM objects do.

Answer (score 1):

`CoCreateInstance` API will look at the `registry` find the module that match specified `CLSID`, load it and the through a mechanism(it depend whether your code is `DLL` or `EXE`) it will call some functions to create your object. So for your code in order to make `CoCreateInstance` to work, you should write a class that implement `IClassFactory` interface of `COM` and register it in the registry and then call `CoCreateInstance` that do a couple of extra work with your code to at least do your lovely `operator new`, then yes of course it is safe. In general it is always safe to call `operator new` of implementation of `source` interfaces(interfaces that only declared for callback) in your code and this is also the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.  This is how a COM server would typically create its objects internally (at least one written in C++).  From your point of view, the RecyclerProgressCallback class is just some C++ code.  You can treat it as any other class in your program.

That being said, COM is a minefield of subtle gotchas.  I can't promise that you won't encounter problems with your class, but I can assure you that those problems will be unrelated to your use of operator new.

Answer (score -1):

It's generally not safe, not just because of reference counting but also because of marshalling: the class may have a threading model that requires marshalling. CoCreateInstance will create a proxy and stub if that's the case, whereas `new` will not.

Comment: This is not true. You will expose interface and COM object, and they would be marshaled by COM the very same safe way.

Comment: No. If the class requires marshalling, what you get from CoCreateInstance is a proxy object, not the object itself. This will never happen with `new`.

Comment: You are making things messy for no reason. If caller needs class on a different apartment, he would `new` from another thread and let COM do normal marshaling. 100% safe and workable. If caller needs `new` for a reason and he takes care of threading, `new` is absolutely safe and reliable.

Comment: OK, but "he would `new` from another thread and let COM do normal marshalling" sounds simpler than it really is. Unless you know what marshalling is (a lot of programmers probably don't) and how it works (even less programmers do), you would just try to use the `new`'ed pointer as the object and pass it all around, possibly with bad results.